# Easy way to check reference count for an object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, memory

In an iOS project using Xcode and Swift, is there a simple way to check the reference count for an object? Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) usually handles memory management for us, but I'm having trouble tracking down a memory leak in my app. I want an easy way to examine the reference count of any object at any given point in the app's lifecycle. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 20):

I found an easy way using a command for the LLDB debugger console. If anyone knows another good way to examine the reference count of an object, feel free to leave another answer.

### Steps

First, use a breakpoint to pause execution at a point in your code when you want to check the reference count of some object. The console will display `(lldb)`. Click next to it to insert your cursor.

[image: lldb console prompt]

Type `language swift refcount array` (where "array" is the name of the object that I wanted to examine; substitute the name of your own object instead), and then press Return. The console will output the object's reference count in this format:

`refcount data: (strong = 1, unowned = 0, weak = 0)`

### More About Debugger Commands

Enter `help` to see more console commands. There are a lot of them. I've been using Xcode for five years and I only just learned of them today. This can be a super useful debugging tool. FYI, here are a few of the most useful ones:

`po self`
Stands for "print-object". Prints a nice description of an object. I'm just using "self" here as an example. You can substitute the name of your own object.

`p self`
The "print" command. As print-object, but more verbose. Using "self" here as an example again.

`step`
Advance one line of code.

`continue`
Resume program execution.

`expr`
The "expression" command. Lets you enter Swift code to modify variables. For example, add some data to an array object:
`expr array.insert(343, at: 0)`
You can even change UI elements this way, as in this example:
`expr self.view.tintColor = UIColor.red`

Comment: You should use Swift native collection types (Array instead of NSArray/NSMutableArray)

Comment: In this example I was intentionally trying to create a bug with `NSMutableArray` so that I could practice using the debugger commands :) Under normal circumstances I would agree that yes, one should use the native Swift types if possible.

Comment: this is good to know, +1. But It's generally better to just Instruments

Answer (score 15):

Just type `po CFGetRetainCount(someVariable)` on lldb

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1521288-cfgetretaincount